# Is there any way to create a copy of a binary tree using a recursive breadth first implementation?

Tags: data-structures, scheme, binary-tree, racket

Essentially what I am trying to do is take a binary tree with data definition

```
binary_tree: number | (symbol binary_tree binary_tree)
```

and create a new version of the tree where each leaf (a number) is replaced with a counter number. I am trying to do this left-to-right and then top-down, so using a breadth first search seems like the obvious choice to visit every node in order. However, my problem is this. I need to accumulate a new binary tree to return it. Is there any possible way to do this since we are visiting each node in order?

So in short if I have a tree defined like this:

```
(define bt '(foo (bar 26 12) (baz 11 (quux 117 14))))
```

i need to process and accumulate a new list such that

```
(define bt '(foo (bar 0 1) (baz 2 (quux 3 4))))
```

Here is my code:

```
(define (number-leaves bst)
  (define (helper queue counter)
    (cond[(non-empty-queue? queue)
              (define x (dequeue! queue))
              (cond [(number? x)(cons counter (helper queue (+ 1 counter)))]
                    [(symbol? (car x))(begin (enqueue! queue (car(cdr x)))
                                             (enqueue! queue (car(cdr(cdr   x))))
                                             (cons (list(car x)) (helper queue counter)))])]
         ['()]))
  (begin (define q (make-queue))
         (enqueue! q bst)
         (helper q 0)))
```

as of now this function returns

```
(foo bar baz 0 1 2 quux 3 4)
```

It seems to me that it is impossible to accumulate into a recursive data definition while processing the tree breadth first. What can I do? (NB: car = first and cdr = rest in the EOPL racket dialect)

Comment: Looking at your example breath first won't iterate the nodes differently. So you mean you want `(foo (bar 26 12) (baz 11 (quux 117 14) 34))` to be rendered `(foo (bar 1 2) (baz 3 (quux 4 5)) 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to do two passes.

1. breath first while making a lookup based on the pairs that hold the leaf and their incremental new value. It's important to use the pairs since the numbers by themselves are not guaranteed unique, thus `(eq? 2 2)` can be `#t` even though they are different places.. Comparing the pairs that holds the twos are guaranteed to be only `eq?` with the very same value.
2. A standard post order tree traversal where you fetch the new values from the lookup.

The lookup should be a hash for efficiency, but it can be a assoc list for small trees. If you expect the hash to do O(1) when iterating over all the element twice will still only make it O(n).